# How to set focus in the search box of mat-select with autocomplete?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I used following `angular` component in my form to add autocomplete feature to `angular material select` component with multiple selection feature:
https://github.com/malothnaresh/mat-select-autocomplete

It is working properly and I can search the list of options for selection.
But now I need that when I click on the list, the focus should be in the search box displayed on top of the list options(above first option in the list) by default, instead of any selected option in the list(current behavior). Because as for now if the list is long then I have to scroll upwards and then click in the search box before starting to search for any specific option.

Can anyone suggest me any solutions for settings focus on the search box.

The angular code I applied to use the autocomplete component is given below.

```js
export type ListOption = {
    displayName: string,
    value: number
}

itemList: ListOption[] = [];
itemValues: any[] = [];

// Refer the multi-select list with viewchild
@ViewChild(SelectAutocompleteComponent) multiSelect: SelectAutocompleteComponent;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.itemList.push({
    displayName: 'item1',
    value: 1
  });
  this.itemList.push({
    displayName: 'item2',
    value: 2
  });
  ...
  
 getList(event) {
        this.itemValues = event;
    }
    
 onClick() { 
 //I tried to set focus using this code. But I know it will not work. As I still need to fetch reference of the inner search text box.
        let innerControl = this.multiSelect.selectElem;
        innerControl.focused = true;
    }   
  
}
```

```html
<mat-select-autocomplete appearance="outline" name="myList"                                                                                 
[required]='true' [placeholder]="'Select item(s):'"                                                                                         
[options]="itemList"                                                                                 
[multiple]='true' [display]="'displayName'" [value]="'value'"                                                                                 
[selectedOptions]="itemValues"                                                                                 
(selectionChange)="getList($event)"                                                                                 
(click)="onClick()">
</mat-select-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can focus manually:

Add an id so you can select it with `document.getElementById`

```
<mat-select-autocomplete id="autocomplete" ...
```

Then focus the select with:

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete').focus();
```

Comment: I did set focus on the mat-select-autocomplete, but it is a component in itself. I want to set focus on an input element in the html of that component. And I want a solution to work with with angular 4.